# Capture screen using CoronaActivity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to capture screen in Android through CoronaActivity but without success. I'm not sure whether this is possible at all.

tried:

```
view = coronaActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()
view.setDrawingCache(true)
view.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this:

```
local function saveImage(event)
    if(event.phase=="ended") then
      local hello = display.captureScreen(true)
      hello:removeSelf()
      local alert = native.showAlert( "Success", "Screen Capture Saved to Gallery", { "Done" } )
    end
end
```

Comment: This won't help me since it won't capture keyboard in case it is shown.

Comment: Just do the hide keyboard command before you screenshot, then use the keyboard show command once the screen capture is complete.

Comment: I do want to capture the keyboard.

Comment: Oh! Well I have no idea how to do that, you didn't really explain it in your original question. Good luck

Comment: I think this is not possible from Corona so I'm trying to do that from native project. That's the question.